# Webpage doesn't render despite viewport

Tags: viewport

The tag "main" has a dimension of 532x897px; Despite the viewport tag, when I emulate the page onto an iphone4, it doesn't resize accordingly and overflows. Please advise.

https://github.com/elegant13/FEWD/tree/master/P0-Intro_HTML_CSS

Thank you,
Abhilash

Answer (score 1):

Try changing width:532px to max-width:532px for the 'main' container. That should fix it.